# Does the p-adic rationals have isolated points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, p-adic-number-theory

Does $\mathbb Q_p$ have isolated points? I think that it doesn't,but i cannot prove it. Any help?Thank you!

Comment: Is $a$ is very small and nonzero, then $x+a$ is close to $x$ but not equal to $x$. Can you find very small nonzero numbers in $\mathbf Q_p$?

Comment: @KCd, a little more help?:P

Comment: Can you answer my initial question: do you know an example of a very small nonzero number in $\mathbf Q_p$?  How about $\mathbf Q_5$, for concreteness (though my initial question is so basic that you should be able to see it for all $p$ in the same way)? Or how about the real numbers: do they have isolated points?

Comment: @KCd,a very small nonzero example would be $p^{1000000}$ in $\mathbb Q_p$ and $\mathbb R$ is has not isolated points.

Comment: So then you've essentially answered your question: just add that tiny number to any $x$ and think about how close the sum is to $x$.

Comment: You mean something like that? $a\in \mathbb Q_p=>a=\sum_{n\in\ \mathbb Z} a_i\cdot p^n$. Then i set $x_k=a+p^k$ and we have $|x_k-a|_p=p^{-k}\to 0$ and $x_k\neq a,\forall k$.

Comment: The series you wrote down is completely irrelevant: you never used it! The second sentence is all you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15320/discussion-between-user113576-and-kcd).

Comment: There is nothing to discuss. You already answered your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Topologically, the $p$-adic integers, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are all paths through a tree which splits $p$ times at every node, it is like a Cantor set, but based on $p$. So it is a perfect set with no isolated point. The $p$ adic rationals $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a union of countabily many such trees, and so there will not be any isolated rationals either.